# Type for functions that accept inherited type

Tags: typescript

Suppose the following inheritance structure of config objects

```
class ConfBase{
  constructor(public baseVal:any){}
}

class AConf extends ConfBase{
    constructor(public a: any) {
      super("A")
  }
}

class BConf extends ConfBase{
    constructor(public b: any) {
      super("B")
  }
}
```

with a corresponding structure of services

```
class ServiceBase<T>{
    constructor(conf: ConfBase) {
        //...
    }
}

type AType = {/* ... */}
class AService extends ServiceBase<AType>{
    constructor(conf: AConf) {
        super(conf)
        //...
    }
}

type BType = {/* ... */}
class BService extends ServiceBase<BType>{
    constructor(conf: BConf) {
        super(conf)
        //...
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to create a map of functions that take config objects and creates a corresponding service objects.

```
let serviceFactory:Map<string, (conf: ConfBase) => ServiceBase<any>> = new Map()
serviceFactory.set('A', (aConf: AConf) => { return new AService(aConf) })
serviceFactory.set('B', (bConf: BConf) => { return new BService(bConf) })
```

However, when TSC is configured to use `strictFunctionTypes: true` the following error is produced:

> Argument of type '(aConf: AConf) => AService' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '(conf: ConfBase) => ServiceBase'.
>
> Types of parameters 'aConf' and 'conf' are incompatible.
>       Property 'a' is missing in type 'ConfBase' but required in type 'AConf'.

Is there a way to make the type system agree with my idea? The dirty workaround is to just define the config object as `conf:any`, but I'd much rather use the equivalent of java's `? extends ConfBase`. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not really interested in TypeScript preventing you from doing this:

```
const aFactory = serviceFactory.get("A");
if (aFactory) {
    aFactory(new BConf("oopsie")); // no error
}
```

Given the type of `serviceFactory`, that code will compile with no error and then give you weird results at runtime.  Also, even if you passed in the right config, the return type is `ServiceBase<any>`, not `ServiceBase<AType>` so you'd be taking the responsibility for asserting the type yourself.

If you're comfortable with all that, then the way to get the compiler to acquiesce is:

```
serviceFactory.set('A', (aConf: ConfBase) => { return new AService(aConf as AConf) })
serviceFactory.set('B', (bConf: ConfBase) => { return new BService(bConf as BConf) })
```

That is, you have the functions accept any `ConfBase` and then just tell the compiler that you will be careful at runtime only to use `AConf` for the first one and `BConf` for the second one.

---

If you care more about type safety then you'll need to refactor this code significantly by telling the compiler about the relationship between the name passed into `serviceFactory` and the particular service being constructed.

Here's one possible way forward.  Let's leave this part unchanged:

```
class ConfBase {
  constructor(public baseVal: string) { }
}

class AConf extends ConfBase {
  constructor(public a: any) {
    super("A")
  }
}

class BConf extends ConfBase {
  constructor(public b: any) {
    super("B")
  }
}
```

Then for the services, we need to make them generic and refer to the corresponding `ConfBase` type as well as the relevant "type" like `AType` or `BType`.

```
abstract class ServiceBase<C extends ConfBase, T> {
  conf: C
  constructor(conf: C) {
    this.conf = conf;
  }
  // shouldn't ServiceBase<T> do something with T? 
  abstract getValueOfTypeOrSomething(): T;
}

type AType = { a: string } // for example
class AService extends ServiceBase<AConf, AType>{

  constructor(conf: AConf) {
    super(conf)
  }
  getValueOfTypeOrSomething() {
    return { a: "whoKnows" };
  }

}

type BType = { b: number } // for example
class BService extends ServiceBase<BConf, BType>{
  constructor(conf: BConf) {
    super(conf)
  }
  getValueOfTypeOrSomething() {
    return { b: 12345 };
  }
}
```

Now we can describe the mapping from name `"A"` and `"B"` to service as `ServiceMap`:

```
// describe the mapping from name to service
interface ServiceMap {
  A: AService
  B: BService
}
```

And the service factory can be a mapped type related to `ServiceMap`:

```
let serviceFactory: { [K in keyof ServiceMap]: (conf: ServiceMap[K]['conf']) => ServiceMap[K] } = {
  A: (aConf: AConf) => { return new AService(aConf) },
  B: (bConf: BConf) => { return new BService(bConf) }
}
```

A `Map` isn't a great representation because it acts like a dictionary where all the entries are the same type.  But here you want to remember that the `"A"`-keyed entry specifically is an `AService`-maker.  So then the following is type-safe:

```
const aFactory = serviceFactory.A;
aFactory(new BConf("oopsie")); // error, as desired
const aService = aFactory(new AConf("yay")); // okay
// aService is known to be an AService
const aType = aService.getValueOfTypeOrSomething();
// aType is known to be an AType
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!